# Arcore camera resolution

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

Is it possible to obtain a good resolution on close objects like text with arcore?

[image: Text close view]

I would need to be able to have a resolution good enough to read text. This picture was taken with a samsung S8 and the arcore demo app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happend to all. In some threads says the same, we have to wait

[LINK](https://github.com/tomthecarrot/arcore-for-all/issues/100)